# Haskell Equivalent of OCaml's Format library

Tags: haskell, ocaml, pretty-print

Does Haskell have a library that does the same thing that OCaml's ([Format library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html))? Or, what is the easiest way to pretty-print an abstract syntax tree in Haskell?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gregory - for you first question - there isn't really a Haskell equivalent to OCaml's Format. Format is half way between printf and a pretty printer (with extra features as well). Jason's answer is spot on for the second question - wl-pprint is the easiest way to print an abstract syntax tree and as was noted, its documentation is especially good.

Comment: you can use `vacuum` to visualize abstract syntax tree: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/87v5v/use_vacuum_to_graph_your_heap/  and  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4-212uMgy8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really like using the [wl-pprint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-1.0) package. It gives you loads of flexibility in very elegant code. See [here](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/pprint/pprint.html) for some nice documentation.

Comment: I second the elegance of pprint. Note a similar interface is also available for OCaml, it's the PPrint package from [Francois Pottier](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~fpottier/). The use is similar, but the implementation is very different.

Comment: The link to the documenation ("here") seems not to be working for me. Site cannot be reached.

Answer (score 3):

Is Text.PrettyPrint what you are looking for?

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Compiler_tools#Pretty_printing

Answer (score 1):

[Text.Printf](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Text-Printf.html),  i guess.